# Sharing variable globally

Tags: angularjs

In my main controller I have a user service that returns the current user.

```
// Curr user
userService.getCurrentUser().then(user => {
    mainCtrl.currUser = user;
});
```

Is there any way to be able to use the `currUser` variable in other controllers without injecting my service and calling this method over and over again in maybe 50 controllers?

Ex.

```
// My other awesome controller
console.log(currUser.fullName);
```

Comment: Whats the problem with using injections? Injections are some of the best stuff in AngularJS.

Comment: You should use a service, which is the standard way of doing it. But if you don't want to do that.. then just create a new js file with your index.html file and create a variable there.. you will be able to access htis variable accross site

Comment: Please explain why Giovani's answer is the right one, while it does not match to your requirements? -> `without injecting my service`

Comment: Please explain why you picked that answer Ørnulf Arntsen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for a **[`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** or [`$rootScope.`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) , if you are sure about not using Providers/Services

**Sample:**

```
myApp.controller('DemoController1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function DemoController($scope,$rootScope) {
     $rootScope.currUser.fullName ="test";
}]);
```

Then access it as,

```
myApp.controller('DemoController2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function DemoController($scope,$rootScope) {
   var fullName =  $rootScope.currUser.fullName;
}])
```

Comment: Hey Sajee, in that way he need to inject $rootScope =) :P He don't want injections... why ever.

Comment: @lin he has problem in injecting service only :P

Comment: Take a look which answer is the right one :D I should had stay away from this. "I dont want to use injections" -> "Use injections" -> "yea right".

Comment: @lin ha ha exactly

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$rootScope` like bellow:

```
mainCtrl.$rootScope.currUser = user;
```

and the other controller, you can recover this as bellow:

```
console.log(yourContrl.$rootScope.currUser.fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want you use controller injections? Use `injector` its the same like injections but also different :D ... like in this [runnable fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sq43bhdo/1/). In that way you still can use services, factories, or components.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = angular.injector(['data']).get('user').currUser.username;
});

angular.module('data', []).factory('user', function () {
    return {
      currUser: {
        username: 'Alfred'
      }
    }
});
```